# Seeking death/burial record in Germany for man born 1922?

Tags: 20th-century, germany, birth-records, death-records, baden-wuerttemberg

I am seeking information for a man and his wife .

He was born in Stuttgart, Germany during 1922. There is no known death date for him.

How could I find a death/burial record for him?  I know his full name and birth date but they are omitted here because he was born less than 100 years ago.

---

His wife died in 1958. I do not have a birth date for her. I know this couple had 4 children. All were born in Germany. The youngest, female, child was taken to the U.S. (San Francisco, California) and adopted. This youngest child was born in 1957. She was brought to the U.S. shortly after her mother died. The remaining siblings stayed in Germany with their father. Any information about this family is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  You seem to be asking two questions: death record for Josef?  birth record for Hilde?  I hope you will not mind me editing it to focus on the first question here.  My recommendation would be to ask a separate question for the second question.

Comment: I just realized that we are on the wrong side of our Privacy Policy which you can read in the [help/on-topic] with three people being named who are certainly or likely to have been born less than 100 years ago, and for the one with a death date no evidence of decease has been provided.  Consequently I will need to remove their names for now.  Please understand that we will try to help but we are bound by our privacy policy.  Perhaps you can start by finding a link to a death record or death/funeral notice for the wife.

Comment: @PolyGeo The names can still be seen in the edit history, though.

Comment: @Bregalad I was going to leave them "half hidden" for a while before redacting but have now done the latter (which needs the approval of a second moderator).

Answer (score 5):

In Germany, records on birth, marriage and death are kept by the ''Standesamt'' (registrar’s office).

Depending on the kind of record, they are kept at least for:

- 110 years (birth records)
- 80 years (marriage records)
- 30 years (death records)

at the Standesamt which has the duty to make corrections and additions to them during this time (e.g. adding a hint on someone’s death in his birth record). See Personenstandsgesetz: [§ 5 Fortführung der Personenstandsregister](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/pstg/BJNR012210007.html). Afterwards, they are handed over to the local archive, in this case [Stadtarchiv Stuttgart](http://www.stuttgart.de/stadtarchiv/).

So if the man’s birth date is known, you theoretically can request the birth record from the [Standesamt in Stuttgart](https://www.stuttgart.de/item/show/305802/1/dept/5675). It will provide you with a hint on place and time of death as well. Why *theoretically*? Before the records are handed over to the archive (see time periods above), rigorous access restrictions apply. Information is only provided to the person of the record himself/herself, spouses, life-partners, ancestors and descendants (§ 62 (1) Personenstandsgesetz: Urkundenerteilung, Auskunft, Einsicht).

Otherwise can only access a record, if everybody who is mentioned there (this includes e.g. both partners in a marriage record) is dead for at least 30 years **and** you can prove *legitimate interest* (“berechtigtes Interesse”), as detailed in (§ 62 (3) Personenstandsgesetz: Urkundenerteilung, Auskunft, Einsicht).

How to proceed depends if you are entitled for access, e.g. by being an descendant. I outline a conservative research strategy, without such a connection.

You know the man’s name and his day and date of birth → most likely not helpful due to legal restrictions right now. You might search in death records at the archive older >30 years for now. Every year, another yearly issue is added

You know the woman’s name, and her date of death. I assume she died in Stuttgart as well. Contact the local archive and get the death record. The death record indicates the birth date and place. Get the birth record from the Standesamt of the place where the woman was born (as you can prove now that she is dead for >30 years). This record should give hints on the marriage and *maybe* on children.

Always request a full copy of the original entry („vollständige Kopie des Registereintrages samt Anmerkungen")! (This is vital, as they sometimes only fill a modern form with the historic data)